# Dominated convergence theorem for $\lim\int_{0}^{n}(1-x/n)^{n}x^sdx$,  $s<-1$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

When I was studying the dominated convergence theorem, I was glad to come across this problem:

Use the dominated convergence theorem (DCT) to show that $$\lim \int_{0}^{n} \left(1-\frac{x}{n} \right)^{n}x^sdx=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^sdx$$ where $s<-1$.

I let $\displaystyle f_n(x)= \left(1-\frac{x}{n} \right)^{n}$, clearly $\lim f_n(x)=e^{-x}$. And $e^{-x}$ is integrable.

The book I am using stated the dominated convergence theorem as follows:

---

**Theorem**: Let $f_n$ be a sequence of measurable functions such that $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere. If there exist a real valued function $g$ define on a measure space such that for each $n$, $|f_n| \le g$ almost everywhere then $f$ is integrable and $$\int f=\lim\int f_n$$

---

To be able to use the DCT it necessary to find any real valued function $g$ that dominate $f_n$. That is where I get stuck, can somebody help me out?

EDIT:
The $\lim$ here means limit as n tend to infinity.

Comment: What's the limit? $n \to \infty?$

Comment: These are not the functions $f_n$ (and you probably mean $s\gt-1$ instead of $s\lt-1$).

Comment: @Argon: Yes the limit is $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Your statement of the Dominated Convergence Theorem isn't quite correct. You need $g$ to be absolutely integrable; it cannot just be any real-valued function.

Comment: Note that $(1-x/n) \leq \exp(-x/n)$ for all $x \in [0,1)$ and hence $(1-x/n)^n \leq \exp(-x)$.

Comment: @Didier: I really mean $s<-1$.

Comment: $\Huge \text{Huge font}$ :D Could you make it a bit $\small \text{smaller}$?

Comment: @Marvis: That is the limit of the function! If that happens then the sequence of the function is monotone increasing which is bounded above by $exp(-x)$ Is that true?

Comment: @HassanMuhammad Yes. To make the argument clear, $$\int_0^n (1-x/n)^n x^s dx = \int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx \leq \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-x)x^s dx$$ where $$f(x) = \begin{cases} (1-x/n)^n x^s & \text{ for } 0 \leq x \leq n \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$ Also as Didier points out, you need $s>-1$. Otherwise $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-x)x^s dx$ diverges.

Comment: @Marvis: It is ok now, I understand you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me write out my comment so that this question gets an answer. The dominated convergence theorem says the following.

If a sequence of measurable functions $\displaystyle \{f_n(x)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, on the measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$, converge point-wise to a function $f(x)$ and every $f_n(x)$ is dominated by some integrable function $g(x)$ i.e. $\lvert f_n(x) \rvert \leq g(x)$, $\forall n$, $\forall x \in \Omega$ and $\displaystyle \int_{\Omega} g d\mu < \infty $, then $\displaystyle \int_{\Omega} f d \mu$ exists and $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} f_n d \mu = \int_{\Omega} f d \mu$$

Note that it is important that the dominating function $g$ is integrable as Henry T. Horton points out in the comments. Also, the condition $\lvert f_n \rvert \leq g$ everywhere, can be relaxed to $\lvert f_n \rvert \leq g$ $\mu$-almost everywhere.

Also, we need $s > -1$. Otherwise the integrals given in the question diverge.

Now lets apply this to the problem at hand. We want to evaluate $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{n} \left( 1 - \frac{x}n\right)^n x^s dx$.

Define $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} \left( 1 - \frac{x}n\right)^n x^s & \text{ if }x \in [0, n]\\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Hence, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{n} \left( 1 - \frac{x}n\right)^n x^s dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{\infty} f_n(x) dx$.

Now note that $f_n(x)$ converges point-wise to $e^{-x} x^s$ on $[0, \infty)$. This is so since $$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1 - \frac{x}{n} \right)^n = \exp(-x).$$

More importantly, $f_n(x)$ is dominated by $e^{-x} x^s$ on $[0,\infty)$ i.e. $\lvert f_n(x) \rvert \leq e^{-x} x^s$. This follows from the fact that $$1 - t \leq \exp(-t)$$ whenever $0 \leq t \leq 1$. Hence, we get that $$\left(1 - \frac{x}{n} \right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{x}{n} \right)$$ which in-turn gives us $$\left(1 - \frac{x}{n} \right)^n \leq \exp \left(-x \right).$$
Hence, $\displaystyle f_n(x) \leq \exp(-x) x^s $. Also, $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-x) x^s dx < \infty$ for all $s > -1$. Hence, in this case, the dominating function is the same as the limit function.

Putting all these things together, we get the desired result.

\begin{align}
\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{n} \left( 1 - \frac{x}n\right)^n x^s dx & = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{\infty} f_n(x) dx & \text{(From the definition of $f_n(x)$)}\\
& = \int_0^{\infty} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) dx & \text{(Since $f_n(x)$ is dominated by $f(x)$)}\\
& = \int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx & \text{(Since $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$)}\\
& = \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-x) x^s dx
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really appreciated it.

Comment: How can I know $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^sdx \lt \infty$ for $s>-1$?

Comment: $e^{-x} < \frac1{P_{s+2}(x)}$ where $P_k(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $k$. Now prove that the integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^s}{P_{s+2}(x)} dx$ is convergent.

Comment: Is $P_{k}(x)$ any polynomial of degree k? Take for example $P(x)=x^2$.

Comment: For instance, if $s=0$, you can choose $P_2(x) = 1+x^2$. Make sure that there is no singularity at the origin when you choose $P_k(x)$.